# Apache Shiro: not able to access secured URL although logged in successfully

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, shiro

Im currenlty working on a Java EE Web application with Spring MVC.
I want to secure it with Apache Shiro and the form-based authentication with the
FormAuthenticationFilter is already working. 
Now i want to customize the login and write my own login-controller.

Here is my Problem: the authentication works, I don't get any exceptions, but I am still unable to acess the secured URL (/welcome.jsp), even if I try to access it directly, although I am logged in correctly (Subject.isAuthenticated returns true) .

Here is my shiro.ini:

```
# =======================
# Shiro INI configuration
# =======================

[main]
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
#authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.successUrl = /welcome.jsp

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

[users]
admin=admin, ROLE_ADMIN

[roles]
ROLE_ADMIN = *

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/welcome.jsp = authc
```

And here is the method in the respective controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", params ={"username","password"})
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
     @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

     if (!this.currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
            try {
                this.currentUser.login(token);
            } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                logger.info("There is no user with username of " + token.getPrincipal());
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
                logger.info("Password for account " + token.getPrincipal() + " was incorrect!");
            } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
                logger.info("The account for username " + token.getPrincipal() + " is locked.  " +
                        "Please contact your administrator to unlock it.");
            }

            catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                //TODO
            }


            logger.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() + "] logged in successfully.");

        }

    String message = "";
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
    String fallbackUrl = "/welcome.jsp";
    try
    {
        WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(request, response, fallbackUrl);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

I would be very happy, if someone could tell me, what I'm doing wrong, I am stuck at this for a few days now and haven't found anything on the web.

With best regards,
M.B.

P.S. I haven't posted my web.xml, and my pom.xml because shiro is already working with the FormAuthenticationFilter. But if someone still needs these files to give me an answer, it is no problem, to post them too.

**UPDATE 1:** It has to be an issue with Shiro itself. If I escape only the last line in the shiro.ini file,

```
 #/welcome.jsp = authc
```

the redirection works correctly and the username: "admin" is only shown on the welcome-page, if I enter the username and password correctly.

For some reason, shiro doesn't accept the authenticated user but I have absolutely no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution, I hope, this will help somebody else.

The problem was that I created a field for the currentUser (as you can see in my method) and I initialized it in the constructor of the Controller. At that time, no security manager was found, so I created a SecurityManager instance too, but now this was a different one, than apache shiro used for redirecting me.

To solve this, i simply had to instanciate

```
this.currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
```

in the respective method and not in the constructor.